# How http listening works

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener

I am newbie in network programming. Dear developers can you tell me what mean listen via http some URL. and in what form information must be on specific address (URL) for to be listen . For example we have `HTTPListener` class in C# and he has such things like Open and event for message receiving. how often he try to get information from URL . Please clarify listening functionality to me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a brilliant article on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx